# What is XSD file? How to use it? Can i convert my stored procs into XSD file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-applications, xsd

What is XSD and how to use it in ASP.NET Web application. 
I have stored procedures (Some of those are returning xml format values). Can i replace those with XSD?

Please suggest some good links to follow. I am pretty new to XSD. 
I am sorry if this question is already answered.

Thanks in advance

Santhosh

Comment: [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xsd)

Comment: Why would you even think of "converting stored procedures" to some file type that you know *nothing* about? -1

Comment: He wants to convert not SPs but their returning values.

Comment: My Client asked me to Use XSD and not to use stored procedures to get data from database. I am new to XSD. So, just wanted to learn some basics how to implement XSDs in ASP.NET web app. Then i can start with actual implementation. That's my intension to post this question. It may not be a good question but your inputs will help me a lot. :)

Comment: Maybe you have misheard your client? Because that's like saying "my client asked me to use NVidia and not to use stored procedures to get data from database".

Comment: "Use XSD and not to use stored procedures to get data from database" - what did he mean? XSD is a document defining some rules, not DB access technology. I think there were misunderstanding, and suggest you to clarify his question.

Comment: @SanthoshA, have edited my answer .. hope it helps you understanding ..

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. Can anyone provide some samples (probably code/ links) to validate the data using XSD in ASP.NET web app?

Comment: The thing i need is this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx

Sorry for misinterpretation :(

Anyways, Thanks all of you people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Mr. Santosh, your client may be asking you to validate the data after
>   pulling it from db.. rather than accepting it right away he intends to
>   get it validated by you. And that is what XSD is capable of ..

XSD: XML Schema Definition, used to validate XML. Usually for incoming data, before accepting it, we pass it through our XSD validation with Schema file. 
you can see Schema file as Set of rules, that suggests how the corresponding XML should be.


With XSD you can not only validate the structure/hierarchy of the XML tags but also,

- You can define Data type of the values of the nodes. [date, number,
  string etc]
- You can also define custom data_types, [example, for node , the possible data can be one of the 12 months.. so you need to define all the 12 months in a new data type writing all the 12 month names as enumeration values .. validation shows error if the input XML
  contains any-other value than these 12 values .. ]
- You can put the restriction on the occurrence of the elements, using minOccurs and maxOccurs, the default values are 1 and 1.

.. and many more ...

There are some restrictions: as like,

- An element(name) defined in XSD file must be defined with only one data-type.
- You can't validate a node/attribute using the value of another node/attribute.

Answer (score 2):

[XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSD) is an XML schema, used to validate XML documents against some rules. This has nothing to do with stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

XSD documents can be used also to build DOM or SAX parsers (utilities that convert XML to object-oriented model). You can use it to build parsers for your stored procedures responses. Google for XML parser, DOM, SAX etc.